# Concatenated string as parameter argument value does not give output in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 management studio.
I have a stored procedure which accepts several parameters.
One parameter name is `@recvemail` with default value as `'B'`.
If the value of `@recvemail` is `'Y'` then all the users who opted for email news letter should be displayed in the output.
If `@recvemail` is `'N'` then users who do not wish to receive email letter should be included in the output.
If the value is `'B'` then all the users should be displayed in the output, 
whether they who opted for news letter or not opted for news letter.

Now for default value `'B'` i tried the set the parameter argument values as `'Y'`, `'N'` but I am not getting any output.

My stored proc is

```
Create procedure [dbo].[proc_getMembershipEmailbackup] 
-- exec proc_getMembershipEmail @From=N'1991-06-11',@To=N'2017-06-14',@DevoteeName=N'',@MembershipName=N'Membership Life',@log_cond=N'',@recvemail=N'N'

@From varchar(10),                                      
@To varchar(10),                                      
@DevoteeName varchar(60)='',   
@MembershipName varchar(100)='ALL',           
@Email varchar(50)= '',                             
@Phoneno varchar(50)= '',  
@MinAmount decimal =Null,    
@MaxAmount decimal =NULL,  
@log_cond Varchar(5), 
@recvemail char(61)='B' 

As   
Begin     
    if @recvemail = 'B'  
    Begin  
      Set @recvemail='Y' + ',' + 'N'  
    End  
end                  
Begin     
    if @MembershipName = 'ALL'  
    Begin  
        Set @MembershipName=''  
    End  
end
begin

select 
            ROW_NUMBER() over (order by mu.f_name) as [No],
            mu.f_name  +' '+mu.l_name  as DevoteeName ,  
            mu.pers_email as Email,  
            mu.home_phone as PhoneNo,
            mp.name as MembershipName, 
            mu.recv_email as optedforemail,
            d1.memb_id ,  
            d1.amt_due as amount_due,  
            CONVERT(varchar(10),d1.nextduedate,101) as duedate,  
            d1.pay_term


from d_user_memb d1   
            left join m_user mu on d1.user_id = mu.user_id  
            left join m_memb_pledge mp on d1.memb_id = mp.memb_id   
where  
            d1.status in ('A','D','C')
            AND(Isnull(@From,'') = '' or CONVERT(date,d1.nextduedate ) >=  CONVERT(date,@From) )              
            and  (Isnull(@To,'') = '' or CONVERT(date,d1.nextduedate ) <= CONVERT(date,@To ))             
            and  (Isnull(@DevoteeName,'') = '' or (f_name +' '+l_name) like '%' + @DevoteeName + '%')
            and (recv_email in (@recvemail ) )
            and (Isnull(@MembershipName,'') = '' or (mp.name) = @MembershipName)     
            and (ISNULL (@Email, '') = '' or mu.pers_email = @Email)    
            and (ISNULL (@Phoneno, '') = '' or mu.home_phone = @Phoneno) 

            --and (ISNULL (@MinAmount,0) = 0 or cast(d1.amt_due as decimal(10,2)) >=@MinAmount)  
            --and (ISNULL (@MaxAmount, 0) =0 or cast(d1.amt_due as decimal(10,2)) <= @MaxAmount)  
            and d1.amt_due<>0  
            and mu.status='A'  
            and (    
    (    
     @log_cond = 'b'     
     AND d1.amt_due BETWEEN @MinAmount AND @MaxAmount    
    )        
    OR     
    (    
     @log_cond <> 'b'     
     AND @log_cond <> '0'            
     AND      
     (    
      isnull(@log_cond,'')=''         
      OR (@log_cond = '>' AND d1.amt_due > @MinAmount)        
      OR (@log_cond = '<' AND d1.amt_due < @MinAmount)   
      OR (@log_cond = '>=' AND d1.amt_due >= @MinAmount)        
      OR (@log_cond = '<=' AND d1.amt_due <= @MinAmount)          
      OR (@log_cond='=' AND d1.amt_due =@MinAmount)    
     )        
    )        
    OR        
    (    
     ISNULL(@log_cond,'')='0'         
    )        
   )

End
```

I tried to execute the procedure with values like this but I am not getting any output

```
use CHTLIVE
GO
exec proc_getMembershipEmailbackup  @From=N'1800-06-11',@To=N'2099-06-14',@DevoteeName=N'',@log_cond='', @recvemail='B'
```

If the change the parameter value `@recvemail` from `'B'` to `'Y'`, I am getting output correctly and all users who opted for email letter is displayed correctly in the output.
Similarly I changed the value from `'B'` to `'N'` I am getting the output correctly and all users who have not opted for email letter is displayed in the output.
Only for value `'B'` I am not getting output. I should get the output such that all users who have either opted or not opted for email letter should be present in the output.

Comment: You cannot use `IN` like that. That's not how the clause works. `IN` must be explicitly defined and not using a variable of concatenated strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mark Sinkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775200/mark-sinkinson) wrote in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840141/concatanated-string-as-parameter-argument-value-does-not-give-output-in-stored-p/30840287#comment49724311_30840141), the `IN()` operator expects a comma separated list of arguments, but you have supplied it with a single argument that contains a comma separated list of values.

Change this part of the stored procedure:

```
and (recv_email in (@recvemail ) )
```

to this:

```
and (recv_email = @recvemail OR @recvemail = 'B')
```

Comment: I assume you mean `recv_email = case ...`. This can result in an inefficient execution plan. The optimizer will cache the execution plan that results from the first execution. If that is a `B`, it will not take filtering of `recv_email` into account, eg ignoring any indexes that include it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks  @Zohar Peled for your brilliant answer. I got it fixed after changing my procedure as per your suggestion. You just fixed my problem in one line of code. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
and (recv_email in (@recvemail ) )
```

is equivalent to

```
and recv_email = @recvemail
```

`IN` works against a list of arguments where you only pass a single argument. It doesn't parse the arguments' contents to see if any of them could be interpreted as a comma-separated list.

If you want to check against a list of options, create a table valued parameter and use it in your `IN` clause:

```
declare @emailoptions table (Option varchar(2))

IF (@recvemail = 'B'  OR @recvemail = 'Y')
begin
    insert into @emailoptions VALUES('Y')
end if
IF (@recvemail = 'B'  OR @recvemail = 'N')
begin
    insert into @emailoptions VALUES('N')
end if
```

This would allow you to joint your tables with @emailOptions

```
from d_user_memb d1   
    left join m_user mu on d1.user_id = mu.user_id  
    left join m_memb_pledge mp on d1.memb_id = mp.memb_id   
    inner join @emailOptions on Option=@recvc_email
```

This allows you to use more than two options, and the optimizer will be able to use any indexes that include `recv_email` to create a faster execution plan.

Comment: Though I generally agree with the table valued parameter approach and have recommended it numerous times both in stackoverflow and other websites, I think you are shooting flies with an elephant gun on this one. I don't imagine having another option to a yes or no question...

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I accepted  @Zohar Peled as my answer since his solution fixed my problem in one line.

Comment: @Zohar Depends on how frequent the call is. If it's once in a while, I agree. If it's frequent, the lack of indexing will be a pain

Comment: @BSG different solutions are appropriate for different scenarios. A once-in-a-while backup may not need high performance. Frequent mass mailings though would, to avoid blocking your user table for a long time. You could also perhaps use different views per scenario (I would) to simplify the stored procedure

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos see my edited answer. there is nothing to stop the database from using any index on the recv_email in my suggested solution...